# set about:config parameter of Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I am using Mozilla Firefox 5.0. 
I want change value of "signed.applets.codebase_principal_support" parameter of about:config using JavaScript code.
Is it possible?

Comment: You mean, from a web site? Definitely not.

Comment: There be dragons there, but no JavaScript accessible properties.

Answer (score 2):

No that is not possible. If you can access to the harddrive you may change the `prefs.js` file.

The file is normally located in windows under `%appdata%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\<randompart>.default\prefs.js`. There you can add or modify such a line:

```
user_pref("signed.applets.codebase_principal_support", <<your value>>);
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment yet, so i wrote this in an answer.
Please do NOT change prefs.js, as the beginning of the file and the official website tell. You can either change user.js, which will override all settings made in about:config on startup of firefox, or use the API (i dont know much about it, look it up yourself) or simulate the access of about:config in the browser.